# How do I match only the main part of the URL with regex?

Tags: regex

Struggling to come up with a neat way to match all of the following bolded terms. Should exclude all leading and trailing brackets and not match anything outside of the actual page url whether provided raw, with domain etc. Essentially is a text box where people can enter urls in any valid way they want and we want to get just the actual page it represents on our site.

https://www.example.com/**page-words**/

http://www.example.com/**page-other-words**/

www.example.com/**page/another-page**

**more-page/some-more**/

example.com/**page-more-words**/

/**doc**/

/**text**

**test**

**other**/

Comment: which language you're working with ?

Comment: There are URL parsers that will do this for you. Depends on which language you use, though but it's not necessary to use regex here.

Comment: Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/h0Cohs/1 captured in group 2

Comment: @MDR - Perfect! Thanks! If you submit as an answer I can mark as a solution? I will be implementing it in python but I was just looking for the raw regex so I dont have to rely on anything python only.

Comment: @Miles np.  Done.  Glad it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given these strings...

```
https://www.example.com/page-words/

http://www.example.com/page-other-words/

www.example.com/page/another-page

more-page/some-more/

example.com/page-more-words/

/doc/

/text

test

other/
```

Try this regex...

```
^(.*?.com\/|\/)?(.*?)(\/)?$
```

Demo (site explains the regex on the right-hand rail): https://regex101.com/r/h0Cohs/1

The required substring is captured in $2 (\2 in Python) so you can capture just:

```
page-words

page-other-words

page/another-page

more-page/some-more

page-more-words

doc

text

test

other
```

Comment: and if has also an html, (such as  www.example.com/page/another-page.html ) I update for myself MDR's formula:  `^(.*?.com\/|\/)?(.*?)(\/)?(\.html)?$`